# Remove hash which contains specific key => value in a recursive array of hashes

Tags: ruby, algorithm, recursion, hash

I have the following Array (no limit of deepness) :

```
 arr = [
   {
     name: "foo",
     age: 12,
     children: [{
         name: "zoo",
         age: 44
       },
       {
         name: "taz",
         age: 17,
         children: [{
             name: 'tof',
             age: 23
           },
           {
             name: 'tok',
             age: 42
           }
         ]
       }
     ]
   },
   {
     name: "bar",
     age: 54
   }
 ]
```

And I would like to remove each hash which contains `age > 40`, the final array will be:

```
arr = [
       {
         name: "foo",
         age: 12,
         children: [{
             name: "taz",
             age: 17,
             children: [{
                 name: 'tof',
                 age: 23
               }
             ]
           }
         ]
       }
     ]
```

Do you have any idea how I should code that function ?

Comment: ok post your answer if you want.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
def deep_reject!(array, &block)
  return if array.nil?
  array.tap{|a| a.reject! &block}.each do |h| 
    deep_reject!(h[:children], &block)
    h.delete(:children) if h[:children].nil? or h[:children].empty?
  end
end

array = [
  {
    name: "foo",
    age: 12,
    children: [
      {
        name: "zoo",
        age: 44
      },
      {
        name: "taz",
        age: 17,
        children: [
          {
            name: 'tof',
            age: 44
          },
          {
            name: 'tok',
            age: 67
          }
        ]
      }
    ]
  },
  {
    name: "bar",
    age: 54
  }
]

deep_reject!(array) {|hash| hash[:age] > 40}
```

Comment: Nice solution. I particularly like your decision to pass a block.

Comment: I just noticed a small problem. If `"tof"` were `43`, rather than `"23"`, `array` would be changed to `=> [{:name=>"foo", :age=>12, :children=>[{:name=>"taz", :age=>17, :children=>[]}]}]`, but the OP does not want the key `:children` when its value is an empty array.

Comment: Updated the solution to remove empty children. I don't know whether the method should return `nil` if the root array becomes empty.

Comment: I probably misspoke. Initially I mistakenly thought your original method returned a key-value pair `:children=>[]` for the OPs example. As that differed from the OPs desired result I concluded that the OP wanted to remove `:children` when its value was an empty array. But you only returned `:children=>[]` with the example I mentioned, so I don't know if the OP wants that or not.

Answer (score 1):

Maybe something like this.

INPUT:

```
array = [
  {
    name: "foo",
    age: 12,
    children: [
      {
        name: "zoo",
        age: 44
      },
      {
        name: "taz",
        age: 17,
        children: [
          {
            name: 'tof',
            age: 23
          },
          {
            name: 'tok',
            age: 42
          }
        ]
      }
    ]
  },
  {
    name: "bar",
    age: 54
  }
]
```

code:

```
def remove_from_children(array)
  a = []
  array.each{|h|
    if h[:children] && !h[:children].empty?
      h[:children] = remove_from_children(h[:children])
    end
    a << h if h[:age] < 40
  }
  a
end

remove_from_children(array)
```

output

```
[
  {
    :name => "foo",
    :age => 12,
    :children => [
      {
        :name => "taz",
        :age => 17,
        :children => [
          {
            :name => "tof",
            :age => 23
          }
        ]
      }
    ]
  }
]
```

Answer (score 0):

The following does not mutate `arr`.

```
def just_youngsters(arr, cutoff_age)
  arr.each_with_object([]) do |h,a|
    next if h[:age] > cutoff_age
    g = h.dup
    if g.key?(:children) 
      (g[:children] = just_youngsters(g[:children], cutoff_age))
      g.delete_if { |k,v| k==:children && v.empty? }
    end
    a << g
  end
end

just_youngsters(arr, 40)
  #=> [
  #    { 
  #      :name=>"foo",
  #      :age=>12,
  #      :children=>[
  #                  { 
  #                    :name=>"taz",
  #                    :age=>17
  #                  }
  #                 ]
  #    }
  #   ]
```